# How i can wait for image data url when ready?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, promise, async-await, leaflet

I want to use image when ready.
My code works, but not every time.

Sometimes the result is wrong dataurl like this - data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAkElEQVRoQ+2SwQkAMAyEkv2X7g6CUIL9nxDtzpG3R+6YDvmtZEUqIhnoa0liMbYiWJ00rIgkFmMrgtVJw4pIYjG2IlidNKyIJBZjK4LVScOKSGIxtiJYnTSsiCQWYyuC1UnDikhiMbYiWJ00rIgkFmMrgtVJw4pIYjG2IlidNKyIJBZjK4LVScOKSGIx9kyRBxCRADOd5J92AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC.

The result must like this - data:image/png;base64,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

I call this function in loop:

```
 function delayedLog(item, urls){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = urls;
        canvass = document.createElement('canvas'), context = canvass.getContext('2d');
        canvass.width = 50;
        canvass.height = 50;
        context.translate(15, 15);
        context.rotate(item*Math.PI/180); 
        context.translate(-15, -15);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        img.onload = () => resolve(canvass.toDataURL())
        img.onerror = reject
        })
    }
```

My loop is like this.
With this loop I load and rotate the markers on the leaflat map.

```
async function processArray(array) {    
    for (let item of array) {               
        url = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/direction_green.png';
        var ico = L.icon({
            iconUrl: await delayedLog(item['Angle'], url),
            iconSize: [(4.5*(mymap.getZoom()))/2, (4.5*(mymap.getZoom()))/2],
            iconAnchor: [15, 15],
            popupAnchor: [-10, -10]
        });

        L.marker([item['Y'], item['X']],
        {icon: ico})
        .bindPopup("<p>Време: "+item['dateTime']+" </p><p> скорост: "+item['Speed']+" км/ч.</p><p> Реакция: "+item['Reaktion']+" </p><p> "+item['Engine']+" </p>" ).addTo(shelterMarkers);
    }
    return shelterMarkers;
}
```

Comment: Where does url come from?

Comment: What sort of `wrong dataurl`? Is it empty / blank, or is it one from a different iteration, or what? You also might consider using `let` instead of `var` in the loop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Your code looks mostly correct (even if a tad weird since it loads the images one by one rather than concurrently)  - it's unclear what you mean by "sometimes the result is wrong dataurl"

Comment: I have several questions. 1. you draw image without waiting it's loaded. if image url is not cached it would mean image cannot be drawn at canvas. was it intentional?  2. your `canvass` and `context` variables are global. was it intentional? 3. and yes, what do you mean saying "wrong data url"?

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete question.
I have edited my question.
Please look again.

Comment: I tried with a let instead of var - no difference.

Comment: so you are getting empty frame without any content, right? so what's about waiting until `img` is loaded before drawing it at `canvass`?

Comment: Yes, i getting empty frame without any content. Before i draw the image in canvass i rotate the image at an angle. How i can wait for context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); ?

Comment: It looks like this line is sometimes not awaiting: context.drawImage (img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); Why?

Comment: I try to await for drawImage with no result: async function delayedLog(item, urls){
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = urls;
  canvass = document.createElement('canvas'), context = canvass.getContext('2d');
  canvass.width = 50;
  canvass.height = 50;
  context.translate(15, 15);
  context.rotate(item*Math.PI/180); 
  context.translate(-15, -15);
  await context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  //await delay();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        img.onload = () => resolve(canvass.toDataURL())
  img.onerror = reject
  })
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank everyone for the advice.
I found the answer to my question.
Sometimes my function returned an empty blank image instead of a finished image because I did not wait to load the resource (img.scr) and so a function returned to me an empty blank.
In my old function this line - img.onload = () => resolve (canvass.toDataURL ()) does not really guarantee that the image is ready for use (the resource is loaded) and returns my response when the blank image is created whether it is empty or contains the resource within itself.
To solve the problem, I used the image-promise.min.js plugin.
Here is the final code that works flawlessly, I hope to help another if there is the same problem.

```
processArray(js_tracks);

async function processArray(array) {
    shelterMarkers.eachLayer(function(layer){
        mymap.removeLayer(layer);
    });

    for (let item of array) {
        if(icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']] != -1){
            var iUrl = icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']];
        }
        else{
            icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']] = await delayedLog(item['Angle'], item['Reakt']);
            var iUrl = icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']];           
        }

        var ico = L.icon({
            iconUrl: iUrl,
            iconSize: [(4.5*(mymap.getZoom()))/2, (4.5*(mymap.getZoom()))/2],
            iconAnchor: [15, 15],
            popupAnchor: [-10, -10]
        });

        L.marker([item['Y'], item['X']],
        {icon: ico})
        .bindPopup("<p>Време: "+item['dateTime']+" </p><p> скорост: "+item['Speed']+" км/ч.</p><p> Реакция: "+item['Reaktion']+" </p><p> "+item['Engine']+" </p>" ).addTo(shelterMarkers);
    }
    shelterMarkers.addTo(mymap);
}

function delayedLog(angles, reak){
     if(reak == 0){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_blue.png';
     }
     else if(reak == 1){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_green.png';
     }
     else if(reak == 2){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/direction_green.png';
     }
     else if(reak == 3){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_red.png';
     } 
     else if(reak == 4){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/direction_red.png';
     }
     else{
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_black.png';
     }

    var image = loadImage(imgs).then(function (img) {
        let canvass = document.createElement('canvas');
        let context = canvass.getContext('2d');
        canvass.width = 50;
        canvass.height = 50;
        context.translate(15, 15);
        context.rotate(angles*Math.PI/180); 
        context.translate(-15, -15);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        return canvass.toDataURL();
    })
    return image;
}
```